# inject html into <li> with js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome extension, and trying to inject HTML into a `<li>`. But it's not showing up. Here is my code:

```
$('.tab-nav-bar .tab-nav-bar-center ul').append('<li class="tab-nav"><a class="tab-nav-button" href="https://example.com">new li</a></li>');
```

And here is the HTML it's being injected into:

```
<div class="tab-nav-div">
    <ul class="tab-nav-bar tab-nav-bar-center">
        <li class="tab-nav">
            <a class="tab-nav-button " href="https://app.asana.com/.../files">Files</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If I do `$('body').append('<li class... >');` it works fine. So I tried multiple permutations of the part that I guess is not working - eg: `'.tab-nav-bar.tab-nav-bar-center.ul'`, `'ul.tab-nav-bar.tab-nav-bar-center'` etc. but can't seem to get it.

I know (I think) my manifest.json is working since the 'body' version works, but for what it's worth, here it is:

```
{
  "name": "Insert HTML",
  "description": "Inserts HTMLS",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],

    "content_scripts": [
       {
          "matches":    ["https://app.asana.com/*"],
                "js": ["jquery-1.8.1.min.js", "javascript.js" ]
       }
    ],

    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "go.css",
            "shawn-test.html"
        ],

  "icons": {
      "128": "icon/icon_128.png",
      "16": "icon/icon_16.png",
      "48": "icon/icon_48.png"
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "goo goo"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two classes on the ul

It should be something like this

```
$('ul.tab-nav-bar.tab-nav-bar-center').append('<li class="tab-nav"><a class="tab-nav-button" href="https://example.com">new li</a></li>');
```

If you are searching in 'tab-nav-div' then

```
$('.tab-nav-div ul.tab-nav-bar.tab-nav-bar-center').append('<li class="tab-nav"><a class="tab-nav-button" href="https://example.com">new li</a></li>');
```

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ne76vrmy/

Comment: that's what i thought, but it doesn't do anything. I don't get it.

Comment: this helps me understand what the order of classes and ul mean, but still doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: Can you put up a JSFiddle for your code so that we may be able to check it thoroughly

Comment: What is the event that you are calling it in? Check this out I created a fiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/ne76vrmy/ Are you calling your code on document.ready?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 $('ul.tab-nav-bar.tab-nav-bar-center').append('<li class="tab-nav"><a class="tab-nav-button" href="https://example.com">new li</a></li>');
```

`$('.tab-nav-bar tab-nav-bar-center ul')` does not work because it will look for **ul** as child for `.tab-nav-bar-center` but in your case `tab-nav-bar-center` is class for **ul** itself. So in your case `$('ul.tab-nav-bar.tab-nav-bar-center')` should work.

Comment: that's what I thought, that it should, but it doesn't. Don't get it.

Comment: i mentioned it in question too, towards the end

Comment: try $("body").find("ul.tab-nav-bar.tab-nav-bar-center").append("your html"),i get the feeling may be ul was added after dom was initialized. or atleast try $("body").find("ul.tab-nav-bar.tab-nav-bar-center") to check if you find ul